# django - import error: no module named views

Tags: python, django, import, django-views

I've been racking my brains and can't figure out why there should be an import error when 'views' is imported.  I get the following message when I visit my index page:

```
"
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/moments/
Django Version: 1.6.1
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named views
Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py in import_module, line 40
"
```

Here is my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from moments_app import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', "views.index", name='index'),
    url(r'^$', "views.choose_dataset", name='choose'),
    url(r'^get_moments/', "views.get_moments", name='get_moments'),
    url(r'^learn/$', "views.learn", name='learn'),
    url(r'^(?P<moment_id>\d+)/$', "views.detail", name='detail'),

)
```

I clearly have a module named views in my moments_app folder.  Also, moments_app is in my path.  Does anyone have any ideas as to what might be causing this?

Comment: `from moments_app import views` has no affect if you use string based imports.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You prefixed your route names with a *relative* module name. Use an absolute name:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', "moments_app.views.index", name='index'),
    url(r'^$', "moments_app.views.choose_dataset", name='choose'),
    url(r'^get_moments/', "moments_app.views.get_moments", name='get_moments'),
    url(r'^learn/$', "moments_app.views.learn", name='learn'),
    url(r'^(?P<moment_id>\d+)/$', "moments_app.views.detail", name='detail'),
)
```

or better still, use the first argument to specify the full module path:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('moments_app.views',
    url(r'^$', "index", name='index'),
    url(r'^$', "choose_dataset", name='choose'),
    url(r'^get_moments/', "get_moments", name='get_moments'),
    url(r'^learn/$', "views.learn", name='learn'),
    url(r'^(?P<moment_id>\d+)/$', "detail", name='detail'),
)
```

although a combination of the two is also allowed:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('moments_app',
    url(r'^$', "views.index", name='index'),
    url(r'^$', "views.choose_dataset", name='choose'),
    url(r'^get_moments/', "views.get_moments", name='get_moments'),
    url(r'^learn/$', "views.learn", name='learn'),
    url(r'^(?P<moment_id>\d+)/$', "views.detail", name='detail'),
)
```

Answer (score 8):

Two year update:

In Django 1.8 and later both string views and the `patterns` function are deprecated, resulting in a simpler and more reliable syntax:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^$', views.choose_dataset, name='choose'),
    url(r'^get_moments/', views.get_moments, name='get_moments'),
    url(r'^learn/$', views.learn, name='learn'),
    url(r'^(?P<moment_id>\d+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
]
```

Note that there are no "relative" or "absolute" view names with the callable syntax -- if you import the `views` module you get its definitions.  I'd avoid importing the individual view functions since there's a tiny chance that another import could define a colliding name.  If you're not worried about collisions and don't mind putting your app name in the file, the urls can be slightly shortened:

```
from moments_app.views import index, choose_dataset, get_moments, learn, detail

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', index, name='index'),
    url(r'^$', choose_dataset, name='choose'),
    url(r'^get_moments/', get_moments, name='get_moments'),
    url(r'^learn/$', learn, name='learn'),
    url(r'^(?P<moment_id>\d+)/$', detail, name='detail'),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have imported your view as

```
from moments_app import views
```

Some times it won't work.

Use this

```
from moments_app.views import *


urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^$', index, name='index'),
    url(r'^$', choose_dataset, name='choose'),
    url(r'^get_moments/', get_moments, name='get_moments'),
    url(r'^learn/$', learn, name='learn'),
    url(r'^(?P<moment_id>\d+)/$', detail, name='detail'),

)
```

It will work..

Answer (score 0):

Just Change import statement to

```
import appname.views
```

This works fine for my code.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem and tried above answers but the issue was that i was missing a string quote in my "render" function in views.py which i missed and was facing issue in urls.py which states that no module "views" is present in "portfolio"(app name).
Hope this helps!